# lightbox activates when clicking the link twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a weird issue where I have to click twice on a link(button) instead of once to activate the lightbox event and cant figure out why for the life of me.

here is my code and here is a preview of the page , if you'll notice you'll have to click twice on the watch button to activate the lightbox event.

(link removed so Google doesn't index)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var src = '';

    $j(function()
    {
        $j("span#btnclick").click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            $j("a.watchbutton").nivoLightbox({
                effect: 'fade',
                afterShowLightbox: function()
                {
                    src = $j('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src');
                    $j('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src', src  +'?autoplay=1');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try extracting `$j("a.watchbutton").nivoLightbox({ ......` out of `click` event.

Comment: weird that worked. hows that possible?

Comment: That is because the click listener for a.watchbutton is defined when you click on span#btnclick

Comment: fairly simple..the plugin has it's own event handlers and when you initialize inside a click event...plugin can't see that first event

Comment: @SarmenB. See my answer, I explain what is happening ;)

Comment: interesting, somehow its making sense in my head. thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are defining the lightbox functionality inside the `click` event. So when you click first time, the lightbox functionality is defined. Second time it's redifined, but before it work because it was already defined.

The solution is to extract the lightbox functionality definition out of `click` event:

```
$j("span#btnclick").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

$j("a.watchbutton").nivoLightbox({
    effect: 'fade',
    afterShowLightbox: function()
    {
        src = $j('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src');
        $j('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src', src  +'?autoplay=1');
    }
});
```